# Using suggestedactions in waterfalldialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

using suggestedactions in waterstepcontext

```
    private static async Task PromptOptions3(string prompt, string optionA, string optionB, string optionC, WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {
        var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply(prompt);
        reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = optionA, Value = optionA },
                new CardAction() { Title = optionB, Value = optionB },
                new CardAction() { Title = optionC, Value = optionC },
            },
        };
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }




    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForRequestStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Save name, if prompted.
        var greetingState = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
        var lowerCaseName = stepContext.Result as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(greetingState.Name) && lowerCaseName != null)
        {
            // Capitalize and set name.
            greetingState.Name = char.ToUpper(lowerCaseName[0]) + lowerCaseName.Substring(1);
            await UserProfileAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, greetingState);
        }     
        if (greetingState.Request == "1")
        {
            var opts = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = new Activity
                {
                    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                    Text = "please work"
                },
            };
            await PromptOptions3("Choose from the following:", "Login to OneDrive", "Upload a file", "Create a folder", stepContext, cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(OneDrivePrompt, opts);
        }
```

The suggested actions do not show up. I expected it to show up and the user can just click it as an input instead of typing. It worked when i tried it in a simpler code not in waterfallstep.. I have no idea how to fix this as I am not familar with the bot framework.

Comment: can you explain in a more detailed manner your problem please?

Comment: What kind of prompt is OneDrivePrompt? Is it just a TextPrompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't know what kind of prompt your `OneDrivePrompt` is right now, but I'm going to guess that it's not a `ChoicePrompt` and, frankly, that's what you really want here because it will do all the work of presenting a set of options and making sure a person chooses one of them.

First, you want to change your `OneDrivePrompt` to a `ChoicePrompt` configured like so:

```
yourDialogSet.Add(new ChoicePrompt(OneDrivePrompt) { Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction });
```

Next you'll want to change your waterfall step to work with the `ChoicePrompt` specifically to let *it* present the options and validate that one of them is chosen:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForRequestStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Save name, if prompted.
    var greetingState = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
    var lowerCaseName = stepContext.Result as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(greetingState.Name) && lowerCaseName != null)
    {
        // Capitalize and set name.
        greetingState.Name = char.ToUpper(lowerCaseName[0]) + lowerCaseName.Substring(1);
        await UserProfileAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, greetingState);
    }     
    if (greetingState.Request == "1")
    {
        var opts = new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Choose from the following:")
            Choices = new List<Choice>
            {
                new Choice("Login to OneDrive"),
                new Choice("Upload a file"),
                new Choice("Create a folder"),
            },
        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(OneDrivePrompt, opts);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried using choiceprompt but other problems arose. I am quite new to this platform and I am not sure if I can post a followup question so I made a new post. I would appreciate it a lot if you can take a look at it again and see what I need to do. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll take a look at your new question, but if you found this answer useful you usually want to mark it as the answer or at least upvote it (or both).